# Understanding Eigenvalues with factor_analyzer and Scree Plots in python

Tags: python-3.x, eigenvalue, factor-analysis

I've done a couple factor analyses now using the factor_analyzer python package. Everyone online seems to use nearly the exact same workflow :

1. fit the correlation matrix of your features without rotation
2. look at the scree plot and find the number of "factors" that have an eigenvalue > 1
3. re-fit the correlation matrix with that number of factors with rotation
4. analyze).

But I'm confused on interpreting the scree plot. My base data is 1M rows x **432 columns (features**). For the plot below, I chose **40 factors** (without rotation) as a starting point to determine the number of factors needed.

Why then in my eigenvalues are **432 "factors"**, for which I find 155 factors have an eigenvalue > 1? Shouldn't there be only **40 eigenvalues**? Why do I have as many eigenvalues as original features? What does setting a number of factors in this step accomplish?

Clearly I'm not understanding how these eigenvalues work in this context, and would love some clarification !

Code:

```
fa = FactorAnalyzer(40, is_corr_matrix=True, rotation=None) 
fa.fit(corr)

# SCREEPLOT # Cutoff >= 1
x = range(1,X.shape[1]+1)
y = evs[0]
n_useful_factors = sum(y>1) #dynamically shows a few factors beyond what's useful (eigenvalue >=1)
ones_x = np.arange(1,X.shape[1]+1,0.25)
ones_y = np.ones(len(ones_x))
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(ones_x,ones_y)
plt.title('Scree Plot')
plt.xlabel(f'Features - {n_useful_factors} useful') #previously said 'Factors'
plt.ylabel('Eigenvalue')
plt.grid()
plt.xlim(0,n_useful_factors*1.2)
plt.show()


print( len(evs), len(evs[0]))
pd.DataFrame(evs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Attempting*** to answer my own question - It makes sense to me that the max number of factors you could have is equal to the number of original features (columns), and by the math-magic of eigenvalues, they automatically line up in order of most to least significant, so the eigenvalues I'm seeing are just the explained variance for each hypothetical factor up to the max number of factors. As such, I'm not actually seeing the eigenvalues of 432 features (which I had thought for a moment).